# How do I create a "fake" dart:io File from in-memory bytes?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the in-memory bytes of a "blob", but the API that I want to process this "blob" with only accepts dart:io File objects.

Is there a way to create a "fake" dart:io File , simply wrapping my in-memory bytes, so that I can pass this "fake" File to my API?

Assume that a file system doesn't exist, and assume that I can't write the in-memory bytes to a "real" file.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you write these bytes in a temporary file, and pass that file to your API ?

Comment: You may as well extends/implements `File` class with your custom implementation

Comment: Well, `package:file` is mockable. You can use that... Then again, if this API only accepts `dart:io`, then I'm not sure there is a mockable option.

Answer (score 25):

You can create a memory-file using `MemoryFileSystem` from the package [file](https://pub.dev/packages/file):

Example:

```dart
File file = MemoryFileSystem().file('test.dart')
  ..writeAsBytesSync(blobBytes);
```

Comment: I think you just need `File file = MemoryFileSystem().file('test.dart')`, it's passing the assertion for my unit tests

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to do. if you just want to create the file, that's it, but the question states that they are trying to write some bytes to a file. this is what `writeAsBytesSync(blobBytes)` does :)

Answer (score 13):

Add path provider dependency on `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: 0.2.2
```

Write byte data to file, use it, then delete it.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

main() async {
  String dir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  File temp = new File('$dir/temp.file');
  var bytes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  await temp.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  /*do something with temp file*/
  temp.delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution assumes there is a filesystem. My original question is asking how to create a fake File without any file system. I will clarify in the original question.

Comment: How does if we create FakeFile class that implements File

```
class FakeFile implements File {
  List<int> _bytes = [];

  FakeFile(List<int> bytes) {
    _bytes = bytes;
  }

  @override
  List<int> readAsBytesSync() => _bytes;

  @override
  String readAsStringSync({Encoding encoding: UTF8}) => UTF8.decode(_bytes);
//TODO all implementations
}
  var file = new FakeFile([65, 66, 67]);
  print(file.readAsStringSync());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the io using the `IOOverides` class. See the below example:

```dart
await IOOverrides.runZoned(() async {
  // Write your code here.
  },
  createDirectory: (p0) {
    return MockDirectory()
  },
  createFile: (p0) {
    return MockeFile();
  },
);
```

You can check the doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/IOOverrides-class.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [cross_file](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_file) when designing APIs that work with files.

In addition to working on multiple platforms, it also has an [XFile.fromData](https://pub.dev/documentation/cross_file/latest/cross_file/XFile/XFile.fromData.html) constructor that allows you to create a file in memory.