# How to write a File variable in Dart without saving it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am following the pdf Dart Package where it shows how to save a PDF file:

```
// On Flutter, use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) library:
//   final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
//   final file = File("${output.path}/example.pdf");
final file = File("example.pdf");
await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
```

What I am looking to do is send a PDF through Sendgrid with uses Base64 encoding as the attachment. This is what I have done but with an error:

```
Uint8List unitEncodedPDF = await pdf.save();
String baseEncodedPDF = base64Encode(unitEncodedPDF);
```

I then use `baseEncodedPDF` and pass it to the **content** key in the body for the Sendgrid POST.

**What I think I need to fix my "The attachment content must be base64 encoded." error message:**

- Save the PDF file as a `File` object in Dart like in the pdf package tutorial, and then convert the 'file' to `Uint8List` and then finally `Base64`.

**My problem:**

`File.writeAsBytes` saves an actual file to the phone's storage, the information is sensitive and I don't want it saved on the user's phone but send through the API. How do I save the PDF file as a `File` object to use it as a variable to Base64 encode it, without writing an actual file onto the storage?

Comment: @KJ I found an answer similar to what you suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57579006/14661648

Will using this package fit my needs? It seems to store it in RAM as you say,

Comment: What is the error you got when you tried `base64Encode(await pdf.save())`?  You should not need a `File` object at all.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes you're absolutely right, the error was `The attachment content must be base64 encoded.` as I made in my post. The fix was embarrasingly simple, the Sendgrid API has another key called `filename`, and they expect you to use the extension for it as well, earlier I just entered the name. But when I added a `.pdf` to it, along with the original base64 code you quoted, it worked wonders.

Answer (score -1):

-why dont you create a global variable in class and set your data into it and send it through api

-or delete file after it sent to API with encrypted name and file extension this would make it hard to user to locate manually

Comment: I thought of deleting it, but I was wondering if some smart programmer could look for the directory and grab the file as it appears and take it before it gets deleted in a script. Though I found the solution to the error I was getting in the API, there was a key called `filename` and I didn't enter `.pdf` in it, when I did now the encoding works, and my previous code now works as intended. So no need for using the File class.